# If I replace the hard drive, do I lose my Windows license?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I dropped my laptop and destroyed my hard drive. I have ordered a new hard drive to replace it and so obviously need to reinstall the operating system. The recovery information was in the hard drive and I didn't make any recovery discs.

Does this mean I will have to purchase Windows 7 again if I wish to get it all up and running again?

Answer (score 5):

You will need to reinstall Windows using the same licence key you used for the first install. Usually you will have a licence key sticker that will give you the key. You may have to order recovery discs from your computer manufacturer or borrow a Windows install disk from a friend or a techie.

Comment: See: [Where do I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft)